Bad readability of front page
The light blue color (less so for visited links) and the very slender font face hurt readability, especially on laptop screens which are sensitive to viewing angle. It is merged into the white background very easily.

The font, color scheme etc used on Bitcoin.SE is a standard theme for all SE Beta sites and is not under the direct control of the moderators here. That said, I can bring this up to an SE employee if enough people feel it's a real problem. I'll let the upvotes do the talking.

Long time since I was on a beta SO site. I remember them having the chequered background...

Yeah, they used to have a "graph paper" scheme, but that got changed along with many other design elements some time ago.

I think all white backgrounds are a problem and should be avoided, hence I use an extension to remove them manually each time. [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha] It would be nice if they were changed server-side, though...

If you think black text on a white background is a "problem and should be avoided" you're going to have issues with a LOT of web sites out there - and there's a large community of UX designers who will disagree with your premises.
